# Pattern for reading and writing files with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

**constants.py**

```
import os

BASE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
INPUT_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'input')
FILE_INPUT1_PATH = os.path.join(INPUT_PATH, 'input1.csv')
FILE_INPUT2_PATH = os.path.join(INPUT_PATH, 'input2.csv')
PROCESSED_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'processed')
FILE_PROC1_PATH = os.path.join(PROCESSED_PATH, 'processed1.pkl')
FILE_PROC2_PATH = os.path.join(PROCESSED_PATH, 'processed2.pkl')
```

**structure dir**:

```
root
  |__ constant.py
  |__ input
          |__ input1.csv
          |__ input2.csv 
  |__ process
          |__ processed1.pkl
          |__ processed2.pkl
```

**data_handling.py**

```
from constants import FILE_INPUT1_PATH, FILE_INPUT2_PATH, FILE_PROC1_PATH, FILE_PROC2_PATH

def foo(*args):
    file = FILE_INPUT1_PATH
    # Here it is doing staff
    # Finally I write data into FILE_PROC1_PATH

def bar(*args):
    file = FILE_INPUT2_PATH
    # Here it is doing staff
    # Finally I write data into FILE_PROC2_PATH
```

Currently I'm trying to use pytest and testing `foo()` and `bar()` but I don't know how to proceed due to input files and processed files are too big and test process musn't override processed files.
One approach is to change definition `bar()` to `bar(path)` and then call `bar(FILE_INPUT2_PATH)` but that it isn't make sense in the code because `bar` always needs to read `FILE_INPUT2_PATH` and it is called in many places.
Unit test for foo() and bar() would test if the processed files were created or not because it depends on `*args`.

So... question is how can I solve it? Does a pattern/good practice exists for this case? What should I change in my code?

Comment: One option is to [patch file path constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252840/how-to-patch-a-constant-in-python) to point to files with test data.

Comment: @9dogs thank you! It is what I wanted. If can post the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> input files and processed files are too big and test process musn't
>   override processed files

Yes, and tests are perfectly suitable for that kind of job. Generic approach is to create a test data (which can be a subset of original data with edge cases included) and place it somewhere near your tests, for example:

```
├───tests
│   │   test_bar.py
│   │   test_foo.py
│   │
│   └───data
│           input_1.dat
│           input_2.dat
│           expected_1.pkl
│           expected_2.pkl
```

Then, if testing functions accept input as a constant rather than a parameter, use [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) to change constant in test run (see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252840/how-to-patch-a-constant-in-python) for a quick reference). For storing output either regular or temporary file can be used.

```
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path
from unittest.mock import patch

import foo_module


TEST_DATA_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'data'


@patch('foo_module.FILE_INPUT1_PATH', TEST_DATA_DIR / 'input_1.dat')
@patch('foo_module.FILE_PROC1_PATH', tempfile.mktemp())
def test_foo(tmpdir):
    """Process input and check result."""
    foo_module.foo()
    result = open(foo_module.FILE_PROC1_PATH, 'rb').read()
    expected = open(TEST_DATA_DIR / 'expected_1.pkl', 'rb').read()
    assert result == expected
```

*NOTE:* [`tempfile.mktemp()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) is deprecated because file is not created on `mktemp()` call thus can be locked by another process. Feel free to suggest alternative approach.